# What is the max variance distribution with fixed mean and support

Tags: probability

Is there a upper bound on the variance for a distribution that is confined say, in $[0,1]$, and has fixed mean $\mu \in [0, 1]$

Answer (score 4):

Yes

Given any distribution with minimum $m$, maximum $M$, expected value $\mu$
and standard derivation $\sigma$. [Bhatia–Davis inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhatia%E2%80%93Davis_inequality) says

$$\sigma^2 \le (M - \mu)(\mu - m)$$
The equality holds precisely if all of the probability is concentrated on the end points $m$ and $M$.

If one don't know the mean $\mu$, one can treat it as a parameter, maximize RHS and obtain

$$\sigma^2 \le \frac14 (M-m)^2$$
This inequality is known as [Popoviciu's inequality on variances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Popoviciu%27s_inequality_on_variances).

For your case where $m = 0, M = 1$, we have variances $\le \frac14$.

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful